# Assigning behavior, events, and handlers from server side code only in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am used to a web UI programming model from Wicket, etc that allows you to define server-side behavior/event-handlers that are called when the user triggers an event on the client, with little or no client-side javascript in the markup.

These handlers are bound to the markup via the element id (in Wicket's case wicket:id).   Simplified code would look something like this:

Scala:

```
add(new AjaxLink("mylink") {
   override def onClick(target: AjaxRequestTarget) {
     service.doSomething()
   }
}
```

Template:

```
<a wicket:id="mylink">Click Me</a>
```

HTML rendered to client:

```
<a id="mylink" onclick="some-generated-ajax-call()">Click Me</a>
```

Is this approach possible in node.js or a related library?  Is it clear what I'm asking?

The only examples I've seen focus on server-side request handlers, and I'm left with the impression folks need to hand-code ajax-calls, event-handlers, etc that call these server-side paths in the template with jQuery, etc.

The benefit is the template needs no logic, and is very easy to refactor, and you can give it to a web designer who knows nothing about the server-side logic or calls.

Comment: BTW, I'm looking at meteor (http://meteor.com/), and it seems close to what I'm looking for, but am still interested in a node.js+??? approach if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Meteor isn't using bindings or Ajax (according to the video) - I don't see it in the documentation but if it's pushing data to the client it's probably using websocks.

Why not use Meteor?  The functionality can be replicated in NodeJS, sure, but it's already available in Meteor.

You could implement something like this if you'd want to use NodeJS: http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

Comment: Thanks, I don't mean to distract with Meteor's sockets, streaming, etc.   Basically that Meteor appears to let you define event handlers outside of the HTML markup, e.g.: "Template.hello.events = { 'click input' : function () {...} }"

Comment: I may go with Meteor if I can figure it out :-)   Though it's GPL, really new, and what I'm looking for seems simple enough that other libraries might do something similar.  It's not so simple that I know how to do it however ;-)